# Creating docker images with services (Service discovery)

Tags: docker

How to create two docker images, one with service A, one with service B. Both images should also contain a consul agent, when complete, they should be able to startup and discover the services in the other image.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 1):

See [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/)

Docker compose allows you to defining and run multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services. Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration.